# Trying to understanding lstrip('0x') behaviour when remaining string should be '0'

Tags: python

Here is the sample code:

```
test = '0x0'
test.lstrip('0x')
```

I expect `'0'` but I see `''`.

Is this some bug or expected behavior? If the latter, what is the best solution to obtain expected output?

Comment: It is expected. Use `test[2:] if test.startswith('0x') or test` or something similar.

Comment: `test.lstrip('0x')` means that every `0` and `x` is striped from the left side. So with `0x0` you end with empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The misunderstanding is thinking that `str.lstrip` strips that exact literal string from the left side of a string. Rather it strips each of the characters in that string.

```
>>> 'foo bar'.lstrip('ofb ')
'ar'
```

If you need to remove an exact substring from the beginning of a string, you may wish to use an approach like the following.

```
>>> s = 'foo bar'
>>> if s.startswith('fo'): s = s[len('fo'):]
... 
>>> s
'o bar'
```